# How to do Grouping?

Tags: sql

I hv a table like this:-

```
Purchase_order  Supplier_number Item_number Quantity    Date
7896            WE345       QAZWS002022     1242            20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS002324     1936            20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS002526     1111            20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS002729     414             20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS002022     582         20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS002022     1           20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS002324     1436            20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS002324     1           20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS002526     634         20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS002729     92          20110131
```

I tried using this SQL:-

```
SELECT Purchase_order,
       Supplier_number,
       Date ,
       substring(Item_number, 1, 5) MainProduct,
       SUM(Quantity)                Qty
FROM   tableA
WHERE  Purchase_order = '7896'
GROUP  BY Purchase_order,
          Supplier_number,
          Item_number,
          Date
```

The output that I received is as follows:-

```
Purchase_order  Supplier_number Item_number Quantity    Date
7896            WE345       QAZWS            242            20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS            1936           20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS            1111           20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS            414            20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS            582            20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS            1          20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS            1436           20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS            1          20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS            634            20110131
7896            WE345       QAZWS            92         20110131
```

My expected output should look like this:-

```
Purchase_order  Supplier_number Item_number Quantity    Date
7896            WE345       QAZWS           7449            20110131
```

Can anyone help me to tweak the SQL command ?

Thanks.

Comment: After asking 42 questions you should know how to format them yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Purchase_order, Supplier_number, Date, substring(Item_number,1,5) MainProduct, sum(Quantity) Qty from tableA
where Purchase_order = '7896'
group by Purchase_order, Supplier_number, substring(Item_number,1,5), Date
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your function on `Item_number` in your group by:

```
select Purchase_order, Supplier_number, Date, substring(Item_number,1,5) MainProduct, sum(Quantity) Qty
from tableA
where Purchase_order = '7896'
group by Purchase_order, Supplier_number, substring(Item_number,1,5), Date
```